# Selecting records by date but not time

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp-classic

I have an old legacy page where I need to select records by date and country/client (one field).

My date format includes a date and time. What seems to happen is when it does the select where query it looks for a time.

I really don't know where to start.

I literally need to select a date and a client/country and it display the records.

I have attached the code for the page below.

```html
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
Option Explicit
%>
<!--#include file="_sinclude/authentication.asp"-->
<!--#include file="_sinclude/fnc_general.asp"-->
<%
Dim strSQL, rsUser, strUpdated, strShowall
Dim strTxtCountry, strTxtDate, strCountryID, strCountryName, strHdnCountryID, strTxtDesc
Dim strStatusMessage, strDelID
Dim nRowCount 

nRowCount = 0

IF trim(Request.Querystring("showall")) <> "" THEN
 strShowall = Request.Querystring("showall")
ELSE
 strShowall = "false"
END IF

IF trim(Request.Querystring("CountryID")) <> "" THEN
 strCountryID = int(Request.Querystring("CountryID"))
ELSE
 strCountryID = ""
END IF

IF trim(Request.Querystring("update")) <> "" THEN
 strUpdated = Request.Querystring("update")
ELSE
 strUpdated = ""
END IF

IF trim(Request.Querystring("DelID")) <> "" THEN

 strDelID = chkString(Request.Querystring("DelID"))

Dim Conn, dbPath 

'dbPath = "C:\Inetpub\visaswift\barcode\Embassy.mdb"
dbPath = "C:\Inetpub\visaswift\barcode\Embassy.mdb" 
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" & dbPath

 strSQL ="delete * from TBL_EMBASSY where EmbID=" & strDelID 

 conn.Execute(strSQL)

 conn.Close
 Set rsUser = nothing

 Response.Redirect("add_date.asp?CountryID=" & strCountryID)
END IF


IF trim(Request.Form("txtCountry")) <> "" THEN

 strTxtDate = chkString(Request.Form("txtDate"))
 strTxtCountry = (Request.Form("txtCountry")) 
 strTxtDesc = Replace((Request.Form("txtDesc")), "'" , "&rsquo;")
  
    'dbPath = "C:\Inetpub\visaswift\barcode\Embassy.mdb"
    dbPath = "C:\Inetpub\visaswift\barcode\Embassy.mdb" 
    Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Conn.Open "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" & dbPath

 strSQL = "INSERT INTO TBL_EMBASSY (EmbDate, EmbDesc, EmbCountryID)" & vbCRLF & _
    "VALUES (" & vbCRLF & _
    "'" & strTxtDate & "'," & vbCRLF & _
    "'" & strTxtDesc & "'," & vbCRLF & _
    "'" & strTxtCountry & "'" & vbCRLF & _
    ")"

 conn.Execute(strSQL)

 conn.close
 
 Response.Redirect("add_date.asp?CountryID=" & strTxtCountry & "&update=True")
 
END IF
%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Flying Logistics Scanning</title>
<!-- calendar stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="_cinclude/calendar-win2k-cold-1.css" title="win2k-cold-1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="_cinclude/calendar.js"></script>
<!-- main calendar program -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="_cinclude/calendar-en.js"></script>
<!-- language for the calendar -->
<!-- the following script defines the Calendar.setup helper function, which makes
       adding a calendar a matter of 1 or 2 lines of code. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="_cinclude/calendar-setup.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function GoToURL() { //v3.0
  var i, args=GoToURL.arguments; document.ReturnValue = false;
  for (i=0; i<(args.length-1); i+=2) eval(args[i]+".location='"+args[i+1]+"'");
}

function showCountry(selection) {
var tempIndex, selectedURL;
tempIndex = selection.selectedIndex;
selectedURL = selection.options[tempIndex].value;
window.location.href = "add_date.asp?CountryID="+selectedURL;
}

function GP_popupConfirmMsg(msg) { //v1.0
  document.MM_returnValue = confirm(msg);
}

//-->
</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
td {  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;}
body { background-color: #FFFFFF;}
.style10 {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.style11 {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
}
-->
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body text="#000000" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onLoad="document.getElementById('txtDesc').focus();">
<form action="add_date.asp" method="post">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td width="100%"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" background="../images/topCalendar_bg.gif">
          <tr>
            <td align="center"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center">
              <table width="100%" height="40" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="225" height="20" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#9BCEEC"><select name="txtCountry" id="txtCountry" onChange="showCountry(this);">
                    <option value="" selected<% IF strCountryID = "" THEN %>selected<% END IF %>>Please select a Client</option>
                    <%
    'dbPath = "C:\Inetpub\visaswift\barcode\Embassy.mdb"
    dbPath = "C:\Inetpub\visaswift\barcode\Embassy.mdb" 
    Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Conn.Open "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" & dbPath

strSQL = "SELECT CountryID, CountryName" & vbCRLF & _
   "FROM TBL_LKP_COUNTRY" & vbCRLF & _
   "Order by CountryName"

Set rsUser = conn.Execute(strSQL)

WHILE NOT rsUser.EOF

IF rsUser.Fields("CountryID") = strCountryID THEN strCountryName = rsUser.Fields("CountryName")
%>
                    <option value="<%= rsUser.Fields("CountryID") %>" <% IF rsUser.Fields("CountryID") = strCountryID THEN %>selected <% END IF %> name="country"><%= rsUser.Fields("CountryName")%></option>
                    <%
       rsUser.MoveNext
       WEND

conn.close
Set rsUser = nothing

%>
                  </select></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
               </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

</td>
          </tr>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top"><table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#9BCEEC" style="border:1px solid #000000">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><img src="../images/clear1x1.gif" width="8" height="8"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="95" align="right"><strong>Add a Date</strong>

            </td>
            <td width="335"><input name="txtDate" type="text" id="misc1" style="width:74px" value="<% =now %>" maxlength="20" />
             
            <script type="text/javascript">
    Calendar.setup({
        inputField     :    "misc1",     // id of the input field
        ifFormat       :    "dd/mm/y",      // format of the input field
        button         :    "misc1_trigger",  // trigger for the calendar (button ID)
        align          :    "Bl",           // alignment (defaults to "Bl")
        singleClick    :    true
    });
              </script></td>
            <td width="46" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="../images/clear1x1.gif" width="8" height="8"><strong>Barcode</strong></td>
            <td><input name="txtDesc" type="text" id="txtDesc" style="width:240px" autofocus></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value=" Add " name="submit"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
 <td align="right"><br>
 <% IF strShowall<> "true" Then %>
  <a href="add_date.asp?showall=true"><strong>Show All</strong></a> 
 <% ELSE %>
  <a href="add_date.asp"><strong>Hide All</strong></a>
 <% END IF %>
 </td></tr>
  </table>

<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" style="border:1px solid #000000">
  <tr bgcolor="#9BCEEC">
    <td width="200" height="28"><strong>Client  Name </strong></td>
    <td width="78"><strong>Date</strong></td>
    <td width="205"><strong>Barcode Reference</strong></td>
    <td width="34">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <% IF strCountryID <> "" OR strShowall = "true" THEN %>
  <%
    'dbPath = "C:\Inetpub\visaswift\barcode\Embassy.mdb"
    dbPath = "C:\Inetpub\visaswift\barcode\Embassy.mdb" 
    Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Conn.Open "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" & dbPath
 %>  
  <% IF strShowall <> "true" THEN
    strSQL ="SELECT TBL_LKP_COUNTRY.CountryName, TBL_LKP_COUNTRY.CountryURL, TBL_EMBASSY.EmbDate, TBL_EMBASSY.EmbDesc, TBL_EMBASSY.EmbCountryID, TBL_EMBASSY.EmbID" & vbCRLF & _ 
      "FROM TBL_EMBASSY INNER JOIN TBL_LKP_COUNTRY ON TBL_EMBASSY.EmbCountryID = TBL_LKP_COUNTRY.CountryID" & vbCRLF & _ 
      "WHERE (((TBL_EMBASSY.EmbCountryID)=" & strCountryID & "))" & vbCRLF & _
      "ORDER BY TBL_EMBASSY.EmbDate ASC"
 ELSE 
     strSQL ="SELECT TBL_LKP_COUNTRY.CountryName, TBL_LKP_COUNTRY.CountryURL, TBL_EMBASSY.EmbDate, TBL_EMBASSY.EmbDesc, TBL_EMBASSY.EmbCountryID, TBL_EMBASSY.EmbID" & vbCRLF & _ 
      "FROM TBL_EMBASSY INNER JOIN TBL_LKP_COUNTRY ON TBL_EMBASSY.EmbCountryID = TBL_LKP_COUNTRY.CountryID" & vbCRLF & _ 
      "ORDER BY TBL_LKP_COUNTRY.CountryName ASC"
 END IF %>
 <%
      Set rsUser = conn.Execute(strSQL)
      WHILE NOT rsUser.EOF
 %>


  <% If (nRowCount Mod 2) = 0 Then %>
  <tr bgcolor="#F0F2F4">
  <% END IF %>
    <td align="left"><b><%= rsUser.Fields("CountryName") %></b></td>
    <td align="left"><b><%= rsUser.Fields("EmbDate") %></b></td>
    <td align="left"><b><%= rsUser.Fields("EmbDesc") %></b>&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td align="left"><a href="add_date.asp?DelID=<%= rsUser.Fields("EmbID") %>&CountryID=<%= strCountryID %>"><b>Delete</b></a></td>
  </tr>
  <%
    rsUser.MoveNext
    nRowCount = nRowCount + 1
    WEND
    conn.Close
    Set rsUser = nothing
 %>
<%IF nRowCount = 0 THEN%><tr bgcolor="#E3EDF0">
  <td><b><%= strCountryName %></b></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><% END IF %>
  <% ELSE %>
  <tr bgcolor="#E3EDF0">
    <td align="left"><b>Nothing Selected</b></td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <% END IF %>
</table></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where exactly are you running into problems? I don't think anyone here is just going to do the work for you w/out any effort on your part.

Comment: ok so my date format includes a date and time. I need to be able to select by date.

however what seems to happen is when it does the select where query it looks for a time...